# Master slave replication - DATETIME columns not replicating the time

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have master which is mariadb 5.5 and slave mariadb 10.3, the replication works fine except for the DATETIME columns which are syncing the date part but not the time.

On master: LastLogin 2020-01-15 15:22:11

On slave: LastLogin 2020-01-15 00:00:00

Running `show create table` on both servers returns identical results

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    ID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastLogin datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=71041 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci
```

`SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` results on slave

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                   Master_Host: 185.244.166.75
                   Master_User: replication_user
                   Master_Port: 3306
                 Connect_Retry: 10
               Master_Log_File: master1-bin.000008
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4275814
                Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000013
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 4276111
         Relay_Master_Log_File: master1-bin.000008
              Slave_IO_Running: Yes
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Replicate_Do_DB: live_wp,live_ms
           Replicate_Ignore_DB:
            Replicate_Do_Table:
        Replicate_Ignore_Table:
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error:
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 4275814
               Relay_Log_Space: 4276462
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File:
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File:
            Master_SSL_CA_Path:
               Master_SSL_Cert:
             Master_SSL_Cipher:
                Master_SSL_Key:
         Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
                 Last_IO_Error:
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error:
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
              Master_Server_Id: 1
                Master_SSL_Crl:
            Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos:
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                 Parallel_Mode: conservative
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 0
```

What could be the issue and how this could be debugged/fixed?

Comment: Do you think showing the table definitions might be useful?

Comment: Running `show create table` on both servers returns identical results `CREATE TABLE User ( ID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, LastLogin datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', PRIMARY KEY (ID) ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=71041 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci`

Comment: Please don't leave useful information in comments; [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/257463/edit) your question instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think your replicated versions are supported; I would be concerned with more than one major version between master and slave (e.g. 10.2 master and 10.3 slave might be ok). Specifically, [mariadb 5.6 changes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/microseconds-in-mariadb/) how datetimes are stored, by introducing microseconds. I *suspect* your slave is receiving datetimes where the times are missing microseconds, doesn't know what to do, and prints zeroes instead of failing.

Comment: I would try setting `--mysql56-temporal-format=OFF` on the slave in a dev environment, and see if the time replicates properly. (Or `set global mysql56_temporal_format = OFF`).